# How to merge two collections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, join

I have two collections called Company_Details and Company_Ranks...Comp_ID is common in two collections. How do I merge these two collections to get complete details of a company.

Please help me

Thanks
Satyam

Comment: Do you intend on melting those documents permanently for refactoring or archiving purposes?

Answer (score 1):

To make long story short, you either do that on *client-side* or consider the benefits of *embedding* those documents.

MongoDB does not support joins, as opposed to relational databases. This is both a pro and a con. It has helped MongoDB's developers to focus on scalability which is much harder to implement when you have joins and transactions.

You can follow the [**DBRef**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/) specification. Lots of drivers support DBRef and do the composition seamlessly for you. You can even do that manually. But most importantly, you can take advantage of *embedding documents*.

**Embedding documents** in MongoDB is a unique ability over relational databases. Meaning, you can create one collection consisting of compound documents. You'll enjoy atomicity, as there is no "partial success", and data locality: spinning disks are better in accessing data in sequence.

Comment: Don't we all use SSDs by now? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, Haha, too expensive to be true

Answer (score 0):

If querying is your motive and you don't want to change your schema. Then, try [Apache Drill](https://drill.apache.org/) which allows you to query with SQLs. Then perform the full join, inner join, etc whatever you want. You can [check](https://drill.apache.org/blog/2014/11/19/sql-on-mongodb/) for drill with MongoDB.

Comment: Is it possible to use Mongodb LINQ to achieve joins https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver.html

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB Version 3.2 and higher we got now the `$lookup` Command, which is the "same" as a Join in a RDBMS.
With that you can easy Query between your 2 Collections and get the Information you want.
For further Details Checkt out the Documentation
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/